# Rails HAML ActionView::Template::Error super: no superclass method `url_for'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, haml

I'm trying to downgrade from Rails 4 to 3.2 so my site will work on Site5 hosting. I can't find this error anywhere on the internets so I figured someone here might have an idea. This is it something with my link_to that's wrong?

I originally had `{:controller => 'home', :action => 'index'}` as the url but both methods give the same error.

```
ActionView::Template::Error (super: no superclass method `url_for' for #<#<Class:0x7f03aea10730>:0x7f03aeb38f40>):
    14:       .container
    15:         .row
    16:           .col-lg-4.col-md-4.col-sm-4
    17:             = link_to(image_tag(image_path("logo.png"), :class => "main-logo"), '/home/index')
    18:           .col-lg-8.col-md-8.col-sm-8.menu
    19:             %ul.pull-right
    20:               %li= link_to('Home', '/home/index')
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by doing the following:

```
.container
    .row
      .col-lg-4.col-md-4.col-sm-4
        %a{:href => '/home/index'}= image_tag("logo.png", {:class => "main-logo"})
      .col-lg-8.col-md-8.col-sm-8.menu
        %ul.pull-right
          %li= link_to('Home', '/home/index')
```